# How to flush stdout in ATS

Tags: ats

I am trying to do animation in the terminal by printing and flushing repeatedly. Is there a way to flush the standard output after writing to it in ATS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you can just do

```
val () = fileref_flush(stdout_ref)
```

If you need to do this all the time, then you may want to use 'setbuf' to disable buffering.